# Getting 404 Error with Flask after logging into Discord Oauth

Tags: python, flask

I am making a Discord Bot with a dashboard. However, when I login with a discord account in Oauth and it redirects to `login.html`, it shows Error 404.

Code (main.py):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from oauth import Oauth

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "PRIVATE"


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html", discord_url=Oauth.discord_login_url)


@app.route("/")
def login():
    code = request.args.get("code")

    at = Oauth.get_access_token(code)
    session["token"] = at

    user = Oauth.get_user_json(at)
    user_name, user_id = user.get("username"), user.get("discriminator")

    return render_template("login.html", username=user_name, userdiscrim=user_id)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Code (oauth.py):

```
import requests

class Oauth:
    client_id = "SECRET"
    client_secret = "SECRET"
    redirect_uri = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login.html"
    scope = "guilds%20identify%20email"
    discord_login_url = "SECRET"
    discord_token_url = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token"
    discord_api_url = "https://discord.com/api"
 
    @staticmethod
    def get_access_token(code):
        payload = {
            "client_id": Oauth.client_id,
            "client_secret": Oauth.client_secret,
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "code": code,
            "redirect_uri": Oauth.redirect_uri,
            "scope": Oauth.scope
        }
 
        access_token = requests.post(url=Oauth.discord_token_url, data=payload).json()
        return access_token.get("access_token")

    @staticmethod
    def get_user_json(access_token):
        url = f"{Oauth.discord_api_url}/users/@me"
        headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
 
        user_object = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
        return user_object
```

Tree:

[image: Tree]

index.html works

login.html doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `/` route twice in your code and your `redirect_uri` in `Oauth` is set to URL that does not exist, that is why Flask responds with 404.

Set the route for your login function to `/login`:

```py
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    code = request.args.get("code")

    at = Oauth.get_access_token(code)
    session["token"] = at

    user = Oauth.get_user_json(at)
    user_name, user_id = user.get("username"), user.get("discriminator")

    return render_template("login.html", username=user_name, userdiscrim=user_id)
```

Then set the value of `redirect_uri` in your `Oauth` class to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/login` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:5000/login.html`

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. So to clarify, is /login the directory and the template has nothing to do with the directory?

Comment: In Flask you don't access HTML files directly like `127.0.0.1:5000/login.html`, instead you write routes that render the specified HTML file for browser. In my code `/login` is a route that renders the `login.html` (`return render_template(...)`), the route could be anything really (for example `/my-route`), it does not depend on the name of your HTML file at all.